# MVVM Light namespace issue - Code compiles fine but no preview of the controls in the XAML file

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, mvvm-light

Any idea what's wrong with the following (MVVM Light) code. It compiles fine but for some reason I cannot see a preview of the controls and I see a *squiggly line* in the EventToCommand (`<GalaSoft_MvvmLight_Command:EventToCommand` see picture below) but it seems to have the right namespace.

Any idea how can I fix it? Or this is simply the behavior expected when using MVVM Light?

FYI - Found a few similar questions about namespacing issues but my seem to be different since the code compiles fine.

```
<Window x:Class="MvvmControlChange.Content.MainPage.View.MainPageView"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:GalaSoft_MvvmLight_Command="clr-namespace:GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command;assembly=GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Extras.WPF4"
        xmlns:Custom="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
        xmlns:ignore="http://www.ignore.com"
        mc:Ignorable="d ignore"
        DataContext="{Binding MainPageViewModel, 
            Source={StaticResource Locator}}"
        Title="Give me Liberty or Give me Smart Basic"
        d:DesignHeight="360"
        d:DesignWidth="488"
        SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight">   


<Button x:Name="Page2Button"
            Content="Page 2"
            Margin="0"
            Grid.Row="1"
            d:LayoutOverrides="Width, Height"
            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
            VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <Custom:Interaction.Triggers>
            <Custom:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
                <GalaSoft_MvvmLight_Command:EventToCommand x:Name="Page2ButtonClicked"Command="{Binding Page2Command, Mode=OneWay}" />
            </Custom:EventTrigger>
        </Custom:Interaction.Triggers>
    </Button>

</Window>
```

**Squiggly Line:**
[image]

**Reference Files:**
[image]

Comment: If the thing compiles and works, the squiggle might just be a bug in the XAML editor. There's plenty. Often squiggles disappear after a successful build, because while Intellisense looks at source files, the squiggler (for lack of a better name) looks at binaries for stuff instead, so (for example) an attached property you just added may autocomplete, but not exist in the binary yet (doubt that's the case here). Good times! What's `d:LayoutOverrides="Width, Height"` btw? I never use the visual XAML editor; ignores my theming and screws my XAML up every time. Puts bizarre margins on everything.

Comment: The code is from an MVVM Light tutorial I found online and since I'm very new at WPF, XAML  and MVVM Light I didn't know if this was the way XAML behaves when used with MVVM Light or as you mentioned it, it is just a bug in the XAML editor.  I deleted the line of code you pointed out and nothing changed. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the record, here is the answer to my question.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/brada/2009/12/11/visual-studio-project-sample-loading-error-assembly-could-not-be-loaded-and-will-be-ignored-could-not-load-file-or-assembly-or-one-of-its-dependencies-operation-is-not-supported-exception-from/